# Finding an rpg system for a long-term campaign

Tags: fate, gurps, besm

I'm starting a campaign in a few months with some friends that never played an rpg,in the meantime we decided to create a setting.
Originally we were going to play in eberron with pathfinder rules but now i need a sistem for the new setting.
We need a system that can handle at the same time steampunk,cyberpunk and D&D style fantasy elements at the same time.
The only systems i can think about are BESM and GURPS.
I think Fate could be a good choice but i don't know if it can handle a long campaign with continous leve ups.
So,what system do you suggest?
The campaign will focus mainly on exploration and social interaction but wil probably have fights too.

Comment: Try googling "steampunk fantasy rpg" and you'll get a lot of hits. Take a look at the *Sorcery & Steam* D&D supplement, *Iron Kingdoms*, and *Shadowrun* for RPGs that fuse steampunk, cyberpunk, and fantasy (though maybe not all three in one system).

Comment: Generally if you game idea doesn't directly fit into some world, you should follow the 90% rule. If a system does 90% of what you need it to, it is a good fit for the campaign. Don't forget to factor in player/gm knowledge of the system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently playing in a GURPS 4th Ed. Dungeon Fantasy campaign, and it has a lot of the flavor of 1980-vintage AD&D, but with rules that make sense.  The tropes are all about player classes and dungeon delving, including some minor changes to magic to fit better with those tropes (only clerics can heal, some spells are short-term instead of permanent), and there are supplements that handle starting with lower powered characters, as well as advancement in "levels".

Of course, the GM can use as much or as little of the Dungeon Fantasy material as he likes, mixing it with standard GURPS Fantasy, or any other flavor, as seems fit.

DF isn't mainly focused on social interaction, of course (nor was AD&D), but GURPS itself is pretty well built for that, so it's easy to blend the RP-heavy and dungeon delving.